# Adding User-Control when clicking a button

Tags: asp.net

I created a user-control (customized calendar - but it doesn't matter).

In addition, I have a button control, and my target is to add to the page the calendar (the user-control) when clicking on the button. The number of calendars in the page is unlimited, I do not want to add only one calendar to the page.

```
protected void addCalendar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // clicked on button, should add the user control.
}
```

The user-control is already registered on the page:

```
<%@ Register src="CalendarUserControl.ascx" tagname="CalendarUserControl" tagprefix="uc" %>
```

Each calendar should be appended to the following div (this div is defined in the aspx page):

```
<div id="calendars-holder">
    // first calendar appended
    // second calendar appended
    // and so on..
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code and show/describe what you have tried.

Comment: I just don't know how to do that. Actually, I guess it is really simple, but I don't know the syntax for that. the action should simply append a new user-control to the DOM (or to the div element).

Comment: And please specify your question. So far you have given us the facts but its not entirely clear what you want us to do/\

Comment: Post your markup code. Do you have a server-side DIV, ASP.NET `Placeholder` or what?

Comment: Edited. hope you understand.

Comment: Yes, you've edited it, but it still sounds like you haven't tried anything at all and want us to teach you how to add a control to a page. Is that it? Please tell me you've already tried some code, just to find out that it doesn't survive between posts - a common, understandable problem that everybody who works with ASP.NET has had at least once. Otherwise we'll mark this question down as lacking research effort.

Comment: Well, I found a solution and posted it here. Anyway, if you have another ways to do it I'll be glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected int countCalendars;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["countCalendars"] != null)
        countCalendars = (int) ViewState["countCalendars"];

    // init
    if (!IsPostBack)
        countCalendars = 0;

    // register existing user-controls; won't occur before onclick button 
    // so ViewState["countCalendar"] will be exist.
    for (int i = 0; i < countCalendars; i++)
        addCalendar(i);
}

// onclick button
protected void addCalender_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addCalendar(countCalendars++);
    ViewState["countCalendars"] = countCalendars;
}

// Adding a new User-Control
protected void addCalendar(int idNumber)
{
    CalculatorUserControl Calendar = LoadControl("~/CalendarUserControl.ascx") as CalendarUserControl;
    Calendar.ID = "CalculatorUserControl" + idNumber.ToString();
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Calendar);
}
```